CPU jumping in garbage after interrupt
I am trying to make an IDT, but when i trigger an interrupt it goes to a location i don't know. I am in 32-bit protected mode using and i am using QEMU.
I have created only one entry for the moment, the entry #0 (Divide Error) and i am trying to trigger it with int 0x0
main.s
_start:
    lidt [idt_descriptor]
    sti
    int 0x0
    hlt

Interrupt Descriptor Table
idt_descriptor:
    dw idt_end - idt_start - 1
    dd idt_start

idt_start:
    dw isr_0
    dw 1 ; The code segment is 1
    db 0
    db 10001111b
    dw 0
idt_end:

Interrupt Service Routine for Interrupt #0
isr_0:
    mov eax, string
    call kprint
    iret
string: db "Inside ISR", 0


What location? The debugger should tell you if you single-step the int 0.  (Bochs's built-in debugger is better than GDB attached to QEMU; it can dump the IDT and GDT to make sure the fields mean what you think they do.)  Why sti?  That enables external interrupts.  Synchronous exceptions like from int instructions or actually dividing by zero will still happen even with cli.

As well dw 1 ; The code segment is 1 is wrong. That field needs to be a selector. If your code segment is the second entry in the GDT then you need to set the code selector in the IDT to 1*8=0x08.

You've also set the high bits of the offset in your IDT entry to 0.  Are you sure that isr_0 is in the low 64K of the code segment?

The sti is maybe a problem in and of itself, since if some external interrupt is pending, I assume the CPU will immediately try to execute its handler, which doesn't exist in your IDT and will fault.  So you may not even get to your int 0 instruction.
